# Possible to connect a VM to a VPN connection on the host that is VM-only?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, vpn

I want to connect a Linux VM to a VPN connection *on my Win 10 host* that only the *VM will use*. Is that possible in some way?

Comment: If only the VM will use it then why connect through the host? Just install the VPN on the VM.

Comment: My main reason for that is to be able to chain two different VPN's, while I still would be able to use my regular internet connection on the host system.

Comment: I know one can do VPN chaining inside the linux VM, but it seems as a complex task to me and i am rather new to linux. It would be easier just to connect via a VPN connection on the host, but perhaps that is impossible if you want to use the regular internet connection on the host in parallel.

Comment: It might be either to run the VPN connection on the Linux VM instead. Otherwise you need to configure proper routing both on the host and the guest. Which probably means you need to do quite a bit of reading on network basics, and routing commands both for Windows and Linux. (I am not sure what you mean by "VPN chaining" - using one VPN over another VPN ("nested VPNs")?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works, although it involves using routing metrics.

In VirtualBox I enabled the Host-Only network adapter for the VM. In Windows I used Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) to share the VPN network adapter connection with the Host-Only network adapter. This will accomplish VPN-only internet connection to the VM, but not VM-only use of the VPN connection. To achieve the latter I had to edit my OpenVPN client configuration by including the `route-nopull` argument and then manually route all traffic through the VPN with a high metric value `route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 default 500` This setup will make the OpenVPN connection VM-only.

You also have to set a system-wide primary DNS server on the linux VM to avoid DNS leaks.

I have tested this setup and everything seems to be working fine.